# Which method of storing USERS, ROLES & TEAMS in my relational DB is most efficient

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I'm working on developing an app as part of my college assignment. It's a project management app, and I'm having trouble deciding the best way to store users and teams in my Postgres DB. Basically, users can signup and create/join teams. A user can be a part of multiple teams (each working on multiple projects). Users also have roles in teams (with varying permissions according to the role) and while they have only one role in a given team, they may have a different role in another one. In addition, users can mark some of their teams as favorites for easy access through the front-end.

I've come up with 3 ERDs to solve this.

First, store all users in one table and and all teams in another. Users table has all the data pertaining to a user, while the team table has the team data along with the members,roles and whether or not a user has marked this team as a favorite - like below.

[image: ERD1]

This will have a lot of data duplication - if a team has a hundred members, there will be 100 entries where teamid, name, description are the same.

So, in v2 I separated them and added a members table. Now, each team is saved once, and so is each user. A reference to the team and user is made each time a user joins/creates a team and is stored in the members table along with the user's role and whether or not they have favorited the team.

[image: ERD2]

But, I thought it might be bad to save roles as a string. If roles ever need to be changed/updated or I need to add new roles/rename roles, it would be easier with an ID rather than a string (I think).

So, then I came up with this.

[image: ERD3]

Now all roles, users and teams are stored once (its possible that I've made the roles table into something like a lookup table, which I've heard is a bad practice). All these can be referenced in the members table.

My DBMS concepts are a little weak though I have tried my best to follow steps to normalize it and bring it into BCNF form. But I'm still unsure if I've done this right, or what to fix if something is wrong.

So essentially, I would like to know:

1. Is my table structure correct or incorrect?
2. Should everything be split into multiple tables, or is some data duplication okay (since I can use multiple or creative queries to get whatever I need)?

Comment: Thought I'd give some more background. Roles could be things like 'Product Owner' who can add team members, assign tasks, etc; 'Stakeholder' who can view progress and communicate/leave comments but isn't an active participant in the project; 'Member' who is a regular member fo the team (can chat, work on tasks but not edit the team or project details), something like that.

Comment: Also, let me clarify how I'd be using the data. In the frontend, a user can view all their projects on the "Projects" page (which will search for all teams that the member is part of, and then list all projects that those teams are working on). On the teams page, the user can view all teams they are part of (app will query the db for all teams that the userid is part of and display them). The teams that popup will have different actions (such as edit / view / add member) based on the role of the user in that team. Hope this helps clarify how I plan on using this DB

Comment: Use text, not images/links, for what can be given as text--namely all of an ERD. Make your post self-contained. Clarify via edits, not comments. Ask 1 specific question per post re 1 specific place you are stuck. Put only what is needed to ask your qestion in your post. Justify your options where stuck per your textbook/reference & explain why you are stuck. Don't ask us to rewrite it to explain. PS "most efficient" means nothing unless you define it.

Comment: "*I've made the roles table into something like a lookup table, which I've heard is a bad practice*" - no it's not. You might confuse that with having a single lookup table for everything. Having one lookup table for roles, another one for e.g. salutations and another one for e.g. order status is perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

I like your ERD3 best.  I don't think it is overkill, I think it looks fine.  Having a "members" table be mostly foreign keys into other tables is a common thing.

It is not necessary to eliminate every trace of commonality in every table - sometimes it is more efficient to put up with a small amount of duplication - but in your example I think your ERD3 looks good.

Comment: Thanks for a speedy reply! Will go ahead with ERD3 in that case :)